# PySpark where clause condition on condition

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm getting Syntax error on below query:

```
df_result = df_checkout.join(df_checkin, 
                                    (
                                    (df_checkout.product == df_checkin.product)
                                    (df_checkout.host == df_checkin.host)
                                    ),
                                    how = 'full_outer').where(df_checkout.rank = 
                                        F.when(((df_checkout.rank = df_checkin.rank) and (F.unix_timestamp(df_checkout.checkout_date, 'MM/dd/YYYY HH:MI:SS') <= F.unix_timestamp(df_checkin.checkin_date, 'MM/dd/YYYY HH:MI:SS'))), (df_checkin.rank - 1)).when(((df_checkout.rank = df_checkin.rank) and (F.unix_timestamp(df_checkout.checkout_date, 'MM/dd/YYYY HH:MI:SS') >= F.unix_timestamp(df_checkin.checkin_date, 'MM/dd/YYYY HH:MI:SS'))), df_checkin.rank).otherwise(None)
                                    )
```

What is the error I'm having ?

Comment: you have a `=` instead of `==`

Comment: oops, it's my bad. You are right. Thank you @BanishedBot

Comment: you can select the answer then

Answer (score 0):

you have a `=` instead of `==`:

```
(df_checkout.rank = df_checkin.rank)
```

should be

```
(df_checkout.rank == df_checkin.rank)
```